Sketching an slope field in a different way
@BlackMild, I am trying to sketch the slope field of y'=x^2-y using your method, the third method in my mind. I have checked that the sketch is somewhat similar to my sketch with my first method (Multiple ways to sketch the slope field using Latex). Here is the code of the third method,
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \title{O_3-D_3-E_3}
    \author{}
    \date{}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x, \y)=(\x)^2-\y;}]
    \def\xmax{5};
    \def\xmin{-5};
    \def\ymax{5};
    \def\ymin{-5};
    \def\nx{15};
    \def\ny{15};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny};
    
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
    \draw[blue,shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}]
    (0,0)--($(0,0)!2mm!(0.1,0.1*\yprime)$);
    }
% Latex doesn't understand the code that I am using from that point onwards in a loop envirnoment.
    
    \def\yo{0}
    \draw[red] plot[domain=\xmin:1] (\x, {(\x)^2-2*\x+2+\yo*exp(-\x)});
    \draw[->] (\xmin-0.

5,0)--(\xmax+0.5,0) node[below right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,\ymin-0.5)--(0,\ymax+0.5) node[above left]{$y$};
    \draw (current bounding box.north) node[above]
    {Slope field of \quad $y'=x^2-y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    \end{document}

The thing is for every x value, it needs to calculate the value of x^2-y, then do the same thing for every y value, it is just like calculating a double sum series and double integral.
This is very interesting because I know how does this thing works but latex doesn't, this surprises me! Like for every x value, latex stops there and it is treated as a missing number, treated as zero. :(
This is the details about the error messages that I have got,

No PDF
This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:

There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors    shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile
again.
The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please    add some content and compile again.
This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists,    please rename it and compile again.


As well as the other messages like,

Undefined control sequence.
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of
a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble
using \usepackage{...}.

Followed by the following,
<argument> (-5.0)^2-\y 
                       
l.28 }
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Same for x=-4, -3, -2,... until x=5.
How can I fix such an embarrassing issue and how close is it to get a slope field using this method?


There was a problem with the declaration of the function f; at least ^ for writing a power which does not exist in TikZ, but not only.  Since I decided not to look further, I changed the call of f by its expression.  I also changed the bounds for x and y to get a meaningful domain for the drawing.
Remark. Take a look at the library math.  The code would be easier to follow and more homogeneous...
The code modified
\documentclass[11pt, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\xmax{1.25};
  \def\xmin{-1.25};
  \def\ymax{5};
  \def\ymin{0};
  \def\nx{10};
  \def\ny{10};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny};
  
  \foreach \i in {0, ..., \nx}{%
    \foreach \j in {0, ..., \ny}{%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{pow(\xmin+\i*\hx, 2)-\ymin-\j*\hy}
      \draw[blue, shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx}, {\ymin+\j*\hy})}]
      (0, 0)--($(0, 0)!2mm!(0.1, 0.1*\yprime)$);
    }
  }
  
  \def\yo{0}
  \draw[red] plot[domain=\xmin:1] (\x,  {\x*\x-2*\x+2+\yo*exp(-\x)});
  \draw[->] (\xmin-0.5, 0)--(\xmax+0.5, 0) node[below right]{$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, \ymin-0.5)--(0, \ymax+0.5) node[above left]{$y$};
  \draw (current bounding box.north) node[above]
  {Slope field of \quad $y'=x^2-y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

